# Convert 1 character as 1 byte in Delphi 2010

Tags: arrays, string, delphi

I know with Delphi 7, AnsiString type is 1 byte but in Delphi 2010, UnicodeString type is 2 bytes.

The following code is working well for Delphi 7

```
var
    FS: TFileStream;
    BinarySize: integer;
    FreeAvailable, TotalSpace: int64;
    fname: string;
    StringAsBytes: array of Byte;
begin
    ..............
    FS := TFileStream.Create(drive+'\'+fname+'.BIN', fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
        BinarySize := (Length(fname) + 1) * SizeOf(Char);
        SetLength(StringAsBytes, BinarySize);
        Move(fname[1], StringAsBytes[0], BinarySize);

        FS.Position:=172903;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
        FS.Position:=173111;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
        FS.Position:=173235;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
        FS.Position:=173683;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
        FS.Position:=173695;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
    finally
        FS.Free;
    end;
end;
```

but it does not work for Delphi 2010. Please help!

Comment: You know why it doesn't work. There are so many resources out there. Have you made any effort to understand this?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/SysUtils.TEncoding.GetBytes and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/SysUtils.TEncoding_Properties

Comment: I have using this too `StringAsBytes:=TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fname);` I checked the HEX code, everything is fine but in fact, it is not right

Comment: If it is not right, not everything is fine.

Comment: Hex code seems correct, but the file has not worked. I don't know why

Comment: Why don't you try to understand text encoding rather than flailing around without a clue? Does that ever work for you?

Comment: Problem was solved, thank you all!

Comment: What is this code actually trying to accomplish in the first place? Note that the original code is including a null terminator in the byte array. If you want a null terminator in the `GetBytes()` output then you need to include one in the input, eg: `StringAsBytes := TEncoding.Default.GetBytes(fname+#0);`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to support Unicode-Chars, I would change it so that it explicitly uses AnsiChar / AnsiString:

```
var
    FS: TFileStream;
    BinarySize: integer;
    FreeAvailable, TotalSpace: int64;
    fname: AnsiString;
    StringAsBytes: array of Byte;
begin
    ..............
    FS := TFileStream.Create(drive+'\'+fname+'.BIN', fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
        BinarySize := (Length(fname) + 1) * SizeOf(AnsiChar);
        SetLength(StringAsBytes, BinarySize);
        Move(fname[1], StringAsBytes[0], BinarySize);

        FS.Position:=172903;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
        FS.Position:=173111;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
        FS.Position:=173235;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
        FS.Position:=173683;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
        FS.Position:=173695;
        FS.WriteBuffer(StringAsBytes[0], Length(StringAsBytes));
    finally
        FS.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: This will not work, `Length(StringAsBytes) = Length(fname) + 1`

Comment: @nguyentu: It will work if `StringAsBytes` is expected to be null terminated. +1 reserves room for a null terminator, `SetLength()` zero initializes the buffer memory, and `Move()` is not overwriting the reserved terminator.

Comment: In any case, `StringAsBytes` is redundant and can be removed. An `AnsiString` can be passed as-is directly to `WriteBuffer()` eg: `FS.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(fname)^, Length(fname));`, or if you need to write the null terminator: `FS.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(fname)^, Length(fname)+1);`